# Pasting and working on value from a file to another file

Tags: python

I make a function which read `text.txt` file and then past the value from `text.txt` file to `n_text.txt` file. In this file I will need add number in front of every line of sentences. Example

input:

```
text.txt
this is my
txt file
use for the code
```

output:

```
n_text.txt
1 this is my
2 txt file
3 use for the code
```

I have try my code like this:

```
with open('text.txt') as file, open('n_text.txt') as file2:
    lines = file.readlines()
    numb = 0
    for line in lines:
        numb += 1
        file2.write(str(numb)+ .join(line))
```

and get invalid syntax error. I don't know what should i do or how should i fix my code, i did try research but didn't find any good result for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('text.txt') as file, open('n_text.txt', mode="w") as file2:
    for numb, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        file2.write(f"{numb+1} {line}")
```

Using `enumerate` means we don't have to count the lines ourselves, we use f-strings to simplify the output text, and we open `n_text.txt` in write mode.

Hope this helps :)

---

`enumerate` iterates over items, yielding an index (starting from 0) and the item.

eg:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana']
for index, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    print(index, fruit)
```

Output:

```
0 apple
1 pear
2 banana
```

Comment: this is my first time i see the enumerate() function, can you make a short ELI5 for it ?
and what is f in file2.write(f"{numb+1} {line}") meaning ?

Comment: f-strings are a way of mixing text and variables. Text in `{}` is evaluated as though it was Python code, and converted to a string.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error returned should tell you more about where the error is. It seems to be on the last line:

`file2.write(str(numb)+ .join(line))`

When you use `.join()`, you use it incorrectly. I also don't think the [join function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) will be useful in solving your problem. Here is how the function can be used, and the output it would give.

`>>> 'hello'.join('hi') 
'hhelloi'`

Instead, you may want to add (+) the strings together directly.

`>>> 'hello' + 'hi'
'hellohi'`

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using the `format` function to achieve your desired result?

```
with open('text.txt') as file, open('n_text.txt', 'w') as file2:
    lines = file.readlines()
    numb = 0
    for line in lines:
        numb += 1
        file2.write("{} {}".format(numb, line))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but somehow i can't run your code ?

Comment: Looks like I neglected to copy the `'w'`  on the first line. Try it now.